# How to make the main axes transparent, while make the zoomed_inset_axes not transparent in matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming, transparent

Currently, the figure I plot is all transparent shown as below, which makes it differentiate between zoomed part and the original part.[image]

Another thing is the location of the zoomed part, "loc" keyword only has 1,...9, 9 options, can I specify the location I prefer, using coordinate for example?

```
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 3, loc=5) # zoom = 6
```

I wrote a simple code your modification purpose.

```
from pylab import *
import re
rc('font',family='Arial')
matplotlib.rc('legend', fontsize=24)

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset
font = {'family' : 'Arial',
    'weight' : 'normal',
    'size'   : 24}
fig = figure(figsize=(8,8))
fig.set_alpha(0.0)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
x=[0,1]
y=[0,1]
plot(x,y)
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 3, loc=5) # zoom = 6

axins.plot(x,y)


# sub region of the original image
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0.3, 0.4,  0.3,0.4
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)

plt.xticks(visible=False)
plt.yticks(visible=False)

# draw a bbox of the region of the inset axes in the parent axes and
# connecting lines between the bbox and the inset axes area
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=3, fc="none", ec="0.5")

plt.draw()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('1.png', transparent=True)
```

Below is the plot of this simple code.
[image]

Comment: Answering this question would be a lot easier if you'd give a minimal self-contained example for us to work on.

Comment: Noted with thanks, sample code added ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before your call to `savefig`, execute:

```
fig.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
axins.patch.set_alpha(1)
axins.patch.set_facecolor('#909090')
```

This will make the figure background transparent, as well as that of the main axes, but not of the zoomed axes.

Then, make sure not to call `savefig` with the option `transparent=True`, because that will remove all backgrounds. Just set `transparent=False` in that call, which is also the default for `savefig`.

Comment: It works, how about the location of the zoomed part, "loc" keyword only has 1,...9, 9 options, can I specify the location I prefer, using coordinate ?

Comment: Ah, read over that one (it's better to limit every question to just *one* specific problem, especially if that problem is referred to in the title ;-) ). Looking at the code, no it's not possible while still using the function `zoomed_inset_axes`. You could replicate the behaviour though, by creating another axes, positioning it yourself and  adding the `AnchoredZoomLocator` to it. If you need more help, I suggest opening a new question, because this will be too lengthy to explain in a comment.

Comment: Sure, very nice of you!